# Saving Variables Permanently

Tags: vb6

I have a variable called random number that needs to be stored when the application has be shutdown or the computer has been shutdown. Every time this number is used I also need to +1 to it.

I have a few variables in my current vb6 application that need to be saved when the app is closed and loaded when the app is launched. Is this possible? I could use a text file or a config file to store the variables?

EDIT -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I managed to fix this problem had just using a simple input and output text file. Please read my answer below if you have the same problem and need assistance.

Comment: -1 First few google results when querying "vb6 write to file"
Please don't ask questions that can be solved by a small google search. provide code and / or attempts you made yourself to encourage a good answer, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you read my question its more complex than a "vb6 write to file" , so please read my question first and then think about it before you reference me the 'rules.' I have done my google searches and have not found an answer that fits my criteria.

Comment: sorry i only read: can i use a text file to write something into it?

What's wrong with that? if you have further criteria then please include them in the question. as of now i feel you ask for: How to write to file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to complete the task by creating a file in my C Drive and putting in the number "123" to the top line of the text file. I then wrote the following code:

```
Function GetPOIRandomNum()

    Dim LineA As String

    'Collect stored variables
    Open "C:\TestPartner\Config\POIRandomNum.txt" For Input As #1

    While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, LineA 'Read the first line in the file
        POIRandomNum = LineA + 1 'Give POIRandomNum the integer from line 1 and add 1 to it
    Wend
    Close #1

    'Save the new random number variable to the file
    Open "C:\TestPartner\Config\POIRandomNum.txt" For Output As #1 'Open for output to replace the old number
        Write #1, POIRandomNum 'Input the new number to the text file
    Close #1
End Function
```

Now whenever the Random number Variable is needed I call the above function.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to save values in VB6 apps was to use INI files. If I remember there are a couple of Win32 functions to read/write them.

They are GetPrivateProfileString and WritePrivateProfileString.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will look into INI files and see what Google has to show me :P

Comment: +1 Here is a good [drop-in module](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/kpIni/) for INI file reading and writing. It's by Karl Peterson.

Answer (score 1):

Using the registry is the correct way to do it.

VB has built in functions `SaveSetting` and `GetSetting` for writing to and reading from the registry.

See [registry tutorial](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?563162-Working-with-Windows-Registry-using-Visual-Basic-6-A-complete-Tutorial) or [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452746/vb6-code-for-reading-writing-windows-registry-values) to help you out.

Comment: Would it still be available after a computer restart?

Comment: Absolutely! The registry is where all Windows' settings are stored. You can view it by running (Start->Run->)regedit.exe

Comment: There are many reasons not to use the registry for this, more so for anything updated frequently.

Comment: Could you perhaps name a few?